# Why highchart not show me in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I'm beginner in asp.net and highchart control,want to use highchart control in my web application web form,for that purpose read this tutorial:
[this tutorial](http://codepedia.info/highcharts-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-jquery-ajax-in-c-sharp-ms-sql-database/)

and write this web service in my project:

```
 public class cityPopulation
        {
            public string city_name { get; set; }
            public int population { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public List<cityPopulation> getCityPopulation(List<string> pData)
        {
            List<cityPopulation> p = new List<cityPopulation>();

            cityPopulation cpData = new cityPopulation();
            cpData.city_name = "tabriz";
            cpData.population = 100;
            p.Add(cpData);

            return p;
        }
```

that web service name is this:

```
WebService1.asmx
```

and in my web form write this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function drawPieChart(seriesData) {

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Population percentage city wise'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Brands",
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: seriesData
                }]
            });
        }

        $("#btnCreatePieChart").on('click', function (e) {
            var pData = [];
            pData[0] = $("#ddlyear").val();

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ pData: pData });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/getCityPopulation",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess_,
                error: OnErrorCall_
            });

            function OnSuccess_(response) {
                var aData = response.d;
                var arr = []

                $.map(aData, function (item, index) {
                    var i = [item.city_name, item.population];
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.name = item.city_name;
                    obj.y = item.population;
                    arr.push(obj);
                });
                var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
                var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

                drawPieChart(jsonArray);

            }
            function OnErrorCall_(response) {
                alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        //*
    </script>
```

before that script write this code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

and write this html code:

```
<select id="ddlyear">
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
</select>
<button id="btnCreatePieChart">Show </button>
<br />
<div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

but when i run project and fire the button,can not see anything,and chart not show to me,what happen?is my code incorrect?how can i solve that problem?thanks.

i think ajax can not call the web service!

Comment: check your `WebService1.asmx` file and make sure the line `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` at the top is uncommented.

Comment: @zgood thanks ,i'm beginner ,can you write code complete and post me?thanks a lot

Comment: Check out my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273320/jquery-ajax-to-asmx-web-method-get-error-as-response/35274153#35274153)

Comment: @zgood where is the this line [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] add?